# Improved `is.language` function in R

Tags: r

In R, is there a function that will return `TRUE` if its argument has type `language` and `FALSE` otherwise?

The `is.language` function does not satisfy this because it will return `TRUE` for arguments of type `symbol` or `expression` as well. Obviously, I could simple check that the type of the argument is is `language` using something like `typeof(x) == 'language'` or write my own function, but it seems odd that R wouldn't already have its own function for this purpose because most types in R have an associated is-type function specific to those types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only object of type `language` that is not a `name`/`symbol` or `expression` is a `call`, for which you can use `is.call`.